# Linq2Sql, DomainService & DynamicData 4.0 INSERT error: "...Id is required"

Tags: linq-to-sql, webforms, .net-4.0, dynamic-data

I am working on a Webforms app (in VS 2010, .net 4.0, VB) that uses SQL2008, Linq2Sql, Domain Services and Dynamic Data.

My problem is that when I try to insert a new record, I get the error: "..CustomerId is required"
but the ID is set as primary key and Identity in the database and the Customer entity in the L2S Datamodel is also marked as

`<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_CustomerId", AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType:="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey:=true, IsDbGenerated:=true)>  _`

So there is no need to manually supply a CustomerId.

Anyone had the same experience?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

GM

Here is a little update:
I added another project, basically the same setup as above but without a DomainService class. So it is just Linq2Sql and Dynamic data. I used the same database. The insert works fine, no hickups here.
So it seems that the issue is with the Domain Service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
GM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copying reply to the [asp.net thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1598299.aspx) so this one gets closed as well]

Hi Gerhard,

Please take a look at [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1593183.aspx), which I think discusses the same issue.  Well, it discusses two distinct issues and this is one of them.  In short, the solution is to add a ScaffoldColumn(false) attribute on your ID property in the metadata class (the one generated when you created the web service).

Hope this helps,
David

Comment: Thanks David for your help. Tadding a ScaffoldColumn(false) attribute to the ID fields (Primary key in each table) solved the issue.